# im trying to find a way to prevent duplicate entry into sql table via python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

i'm trying to find a way to prevent duplicate entry into sql table via python. any idea how?

```
input_bp_description = input("please enter category")

sql_scripts = "INSERT INTO bp(systolic, diastolic, description) values(?,?,?)"
data = [input_bp_systolic, input_bp_diastolic, input_bp_description ]
(SELECT systolic FROM bp WHERE input_bp_systolic);
#ideally there should be a check here to prevent the enry of the same systolic!
cur.execute(sql_scripts, data)
con.commit()
```

Comment: Couldn't you just make the systolic column unique? https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/unique.php

Comment: The `systolic` column in the database should have a unique constraint to prevent this from happening. Then your Python script just needs to handle any errors resulting from an attempt to add a duplicate value, rather than trying to avoid adding the duplicate in the first place.

Comment: cheers for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a unique constraint up in the database. That will prevent the duplicate being stored in the first place.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX your_unique_index ON bp(systolic);
```

Wrap the database calls in a `try...except`.

```
try:
    cur.execute(sql_scripts, data)
    con.commit()
except sqlite3.Error as e:
    print('Could not save', str(e))
```

You can extend the `except` clause to deal differently with the different error messages you might get.